# Order groups by percent positives

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(condition = c("renal", "cardiac", "cardiac", "cardiac", 
"cardiac", "infection", "infection", "movement_immobility", "hyper_hypo", 
"cardiac", "infection", "renal", "cardiac", "renal", "renal", 
"hyper_hypo", "hyper_hypo", "infection", "movement_immobility", 
"hyper_hypo"), value = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), n = c(76570L, 48959L, 46816L, 46816L, 
46816L, 72007L, 23768L, 77433L, 62195L, 48959L, 23768L, 76570L, 
46816L, 76570L, 76570L, 62195L, 62195L, 72007L, 77433L, 33580L
), P = c(0.799477943095797, 0.511187679457061, 0.488812320542939, 
0.488812320542939, 0.488812320542939, 0.751835030018272, 0.248164969981728, 
0.808488645262334, 0.649386583137562, 0.511187679457061, 0.248164969981728, 
0.799477943095797, 0.488812320542939, 0.799477943095797, 0.799477943095797, 
0.649386583137562, 0.649386583137562, 0.751835030018272, 0.808488645262334, 
0.350613416862438)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

True + False from each condition sum up to 1. I would like to order the 5 condition groups by the percentage of positives, such that "cardiac", with 48.9% positives will get the value 1, and so on. So on the one hand I am ignoring the negatives for the calculation but on the other hand assigning the value 1 to them, too.

How can I achieve this with dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `arrange` data by descending order of `value` and `P`, create a group id and keep only 1 row for each `condition`. To get the original dataframe back with `group` column you can join this summarised data with `df`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(-value, -P) %>%
  mutate(group = match(condition, unique(condition))) %>%
  distinct(condition, group) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'condition')


#  condition           group value     n     P
#   <chr>               <int> <lgl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 cardiac                 1 FALSE 48959 0.511
# 2 cardiac                 1 TRUE  46816 0.489
# 3 cardiac                 1 TRUE  46816 0.489
# 4 cardiac                 1 TRUE  46816 0.489
# 5 cardiac                 1 FALSE 48959 0.511
# 6 cardiac                 1 TRUE  46816 0.489
# 7 hyper_hypo              2 FALSE 62195 0.649
# 8 hyper_hypo              2 FALSE 62195 0.649
#...
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df %>% group_by(condition) %>% filter(value) %>% arrange(desc(P)) %>% distinct() %>% right_join(df)
Joining, by = c("condition", "value", "n", "P")
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   condition [5]
   condition           value     n     P
   <chr>               <lgl> <int> <dbl>
 1 cardiac             TRUE  46816 0.489
 2 cardiac             TRUE  46816 0.489
 3 cardiac             TRUE  46816 0.489
 4 cardiac             TRUE  46816 0.489
 5 hyper_hypo          TRUE  33580 0.351
 6 infection           TRUE  23768 0.248
 7 infection           TRUE  23768 0.248
 8 renal               FALSE 76570 0.799
 9 cardiac             FALSE 48959 0.511
10 infection           FALSE 72007 0.752
11 movement_immobility FALSE 77433 0.808
12 hyper_hypo          FALSE 62195 0.649
13 cardiac             FALSE 48959 0.511
14 renal               FALSE 76570 0.799
15 renal               FALSE 76570 0.799
16 renal               FALSE 76570 0.799
17 hyper_hypo          FALSE 62195 0.649
18 hyper_hypo          FALSE 62195 0.649
19 infection           FALSE 72007 0.752
20 movement_immobility FALSE 77433 0.808
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this without joining

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(factor(condition, levels = 
       unique(condition[value][order(-P[value])])), condition)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 4
#   condition           value     n     P
#   <chr>               <lgl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 cardiac             FALSE 48959 0.511
# 2 cardiac             TRUE  46816 0.489
# 3 cardiac             TRUE  46816 0.489
# 4 cardiac             TRUE  46816 0.489
# 5 cardiac             FALSE 48959 0.511
# 6 cardiac             TRUE  46816 0.489
# 7 hyper_hypo          FALSE 62195 0.649
# 8 hyper_hypo          FALSE 62195 0.649
# 9 hyper_hypo          FALSE 62195 0.649
#10 hyper_hypo          TRUE  33580 0.351
#11 infection           FALSE 72007 0.752
#12 infection           TRUE  23768 0.248
#13 infection           TRUE  23768 0.248
#14 infection           FALSE 72007 0.752
#15 movement_immobility FALSE 77433 0.808
#16 movement_immobility FALSE 77433 0.808
#17 renal               FALSE 76570 0.799
#18 renal               FALSE 76570 0.799
#19 renal               FALSE 76570 0.799
#20 renal               FALSE 76570 0.799
```